# Como diminuir tamanho de Cards no Boostrap

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, boot

Olá, estou editando um template em boostrap na raça, porém não estou conseguindo organizar uma página com cards e colunas. Gostaria de diminuir o tamanho dos cards de forma que caibam quatro por linha.

Meu site: http://tratspay.com/app/meus-produtos.html

Código até aqui:

```
<!-- Card -->
            <div class="card"> <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="dist/img/img12.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Nome do Produto</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Vendas: 1234</p>
                <p>Afiliados: 123 </p>
                 <p>Preço: R$ 123,12</p>
                 <p>Cadastrado em: 22/12/12<p>


                 </p>
                <a href="editar-produto.html" class="btn btn-primary">Editar Produto</a> </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card --> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 m-b-3"> 
           <!-- Card -->
            <div class="card"> <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="dist/img/img12.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Nome do Produto</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Vendas: 1234</p>
                <p>Afiliados: 123 </p>
                 <p>Preço: R$ 123,12</p>
                 <p>Cadastrado em: 22/12/12<p>

                 </p>
                <a href="editar-produto.html" class="btn btn-primary">Editar Produto</a> </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card --> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 m-b-3"> 
            <!-- Card -->
            <div class="card"> <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="dist/img/img12.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Nome do Produto</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Vendas: 1234</p>
                <p>Afiliados: 123 </p>
                 <p>Preço: R$ 123,12</p>
                 <p>Cadastrado em: 22/12/12<p>

                 </p>
                <a href="editar-produto.html" class="btn btn-primary">Editar Produto</a> </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card --> 
          </div>


          </div>


          <div class="col-lg-12 m-t-6">


                </div


            </div>
          </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Sua div class card aqui</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Sua div class card aqui</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Sua div class card aqui</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Sua div class card aqui</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Ajudou pra caramba!

Comment: http://tratspay.com/app/meus-produtos.html já consegui alterar no site. Ficou show de bola! Valeu mesmo! De verdade! Sou bem iniciante no frontend e boostrap, tô editando várias coisas nesse template na raça mesmo kk

Answer (score 2):

O grid do Bootstrap pode ser dividido em até dose colunas, logo o seu grid para ter 4 cards por linha vc precisa de `4 col-3`, totalizando `12 col` (4x3=12)

Recomendo fortemente que leia a documentação oficial do grid para entender melhor como funcionam essas divisões das colunas: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Veja essa imagem com a edição feita diretamente no site

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!!!!

Comment: @IgorRosa que bom que deu certo! Se alguma resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta :) Assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita. Basta vc escolher a resposta que acredita que resolveu melhor o seu problema e marcar o ✔, vc só pode marcar uma resposta infelizmente.

Comment: http://tratspay.com/app/meus-produtos.html já consegui alterar no site. Ficou show de bola! Valeu mesmo! De verdade! Sou bem iniciante no frontend e boostrap, tô editando várias coisas nesse template na raça mesmo kk